Inequalities of Hessian of distance functions on complete non-compact Riemannian Manifolds
I am interested in finding some inequalities relating the following expression with the curvature on a non-compact Riemannian Manifold
$\frac{1}{d_1}Hess^{d_1} (\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha},\nabla_g d_2) + \frac{1}{d_2}Hess^{d_2} (\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha},\nabla_g d_1) $
Here I am considering $(M^n,g)$ a complete Riemannian manifold, $\nabla_g$ is the gradient w.r.t. the metric $g$, $d_1$ and $d_2$ are the distance functions to a point (different points for each) and Hess is the Hessian operator of $d_1$ and $d_2$ respectively. As I said, I would appreciate some inequalities relating this expression to the curvature of the manifold, since I am not really an expert in Riemannian geometry and I cannot quite found I needed.
